# Kubernetes nodes unavailable with insufficient CPU

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes cluster and when I try to scale a Deployment up to 8 pods, it gives an error message:

"0/3 nodes are available: 3 insufficient cpu."

After some time it shows 3/8 pods available and then 5/8 pods available with the same error, but never reached 8 pods.

Recently we introduced CPU limits on Pods.

What is the cause and solution for this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scheduler is not able to schedule pods to any of 3 nodes as required resources are not available on nodes.

This may be due to cpu request value of pod is more than available cpu  of nodes or actually your nodes don't have any cpu capacity left to schedule new pods.

Check available cpu capacity of nodes and increase it by removing non required pods. Also reduce cpu request value of pod if specified.

Comment: Or of course create the OP could create more nodes that would add more CPU resource into the cluster...

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your resources requests cpu is less than limits cpu.